# selection and blur event in firefox

Tags: firefox, selection, contenteditable, blur

I apologize for my bad English.
I make a simple wysiwyg text editor and ran into a problem in the Firefox browser.
If the focus is lost from the contenteditable block, the function saves the selection, for later applying the action to it via execCommand. In IE11, EDGE, Chrome everything is fine, the selection is saved and you can restore it later. In Firefox, if you lose focus by clicking on another item, the selection of this element is retained, and not the one to which the blur event is associated. That is, the event triggers with lateness and writes to the Selection object a reference to the range in the element that was clicked. Such a bug occurs only when the focus is lost through a click, through switching on clicking on TAB, everything works as it should.

Below is a small example of this bug. Again, the problem occurs in Firefox.

```js
function sel() {
     var selection;
     if (document.getSelection !== undefined) {
         selection = document.getSelection();
         if (selection.getRangeAt && selection.rangeCount) {
             console.log(selection.getRangeAt(0));
          }
      } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
          console.log(document.selection.createRange());
      }
    };

    document.getElementById("c").addEventListener("blur", sel, { capture: true });
```

```html
<div id="c" contenteditable="true" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; border : 1px solid black;">ccccc</div>
<div id="b" style="width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: green;">bbbbb</div>
```

I await your advice, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox is very Disappointed

```js
            function bindBeforeBlur(dom, callback){
                dom.addEventListener('focus', function(){
                    document.addEventListener('mousedown', callback, {
                        once: true
                    })
                })
                dom.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
                    e.stopPropagation();
                })
                dom.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
                    if(e.key === 'Tab'){
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                })
            }

            var editable = document.getElementById('editable');
            
            var lastRange;
            bindBeforeBlur(editable, function(e){
                lastRange = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            })

            editable.focus();

            document.getElementById('insert')
            .addEventListener('click', function(){
                var sel = window.getSelection();
                sel.removeAllRanges();
                sel.addRange(lastRange);
                document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, Date.now() + ' ');
            })
```

```html
        <button id="insert">insert</button>
        <div id="editable" contenteditable="true" 
        style="height: 400px;width: 400px;background: #eee"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Good decision. I replaced the Blur event with Mouseleave with a check for the emptiness of the variable in which the selection-range is stored.